# How to open dlt viewer in linux

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, dlt-daemon

I have used dlt viewer gui using windows where I can able to set the ECU IP and connect. Now, I have been moved to Linux (ubuntu). I am not getting how to launch dlt viewer gui. I have followed,

> https://github.com/GENIVI/dlt-viewer.

And referred many links, i don't see how we can use GUI as windows. Can any one suggest where can I find the information to use dlt viewer in Linux.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. Please ensure you include the [Minimum Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can ensure we assist you as best as we can.

Comment: @joshua Since i don't know how to use DLT viewer in linux, i am not sure i can give more information apart from this. I would like to you use dlt viewer gui in linux as in windows.

Answer (score 1):

Tried Yesterday with Ubuntu 16.04 and it was easy following the commands listed in the 'INSTALL.md' file, you will need to install Qt. I paste them here for your utility.

Open a console in the local checkout of dlt-viewer repository.

Instructions for installing DLT Viewer (Linux command line)

```
sudo apt install build-essential
sudo apt install qtcreator
sudo apt install qt5-default
sudo apt install libqt5serialport5-dev
mkdir build
cd build
qmake ../BuildDltViewer.pro
make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
Optional: set the library path: LD_LIBRARY_PATH = .
```

once it's installed, just call dlt-viewer from the console to open it up.

Answer (score 0):

```
I am attaching a script which I use to download and install dlt-viewer on ubuntu.

#! /usr/bin/env bash

DLT_DIRECTORY=$(pwd)
DLT_FOLDER="dlt-viewer"


echo "pwd = $(pwd)"

if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
  echo "Path to dlt-viewer is not provided, using the current location for installation";
else
  DLT_DIRECTORY=$1
fi

function CheckIfDltExists()
{
  cd $DLT_DIRECTORY;

  if [ ! -d "$DLT_FOLDER" ]; then
    echo "$DLT_DIRECTORY/$DLT_FOLDER does not exist..."
    echo "Clonig from github..."

  git clone https://github.com/GENIVI/dlt-viewer.git
  fi
}

function SetUpEnvForDlt()
{
  echo "found dlt-viewer in $pwd folder"
  echo "Setting up environment"

  cd $DLT_DIRECTORY; sudo apt-get update;
  sudo apt install build-essential ; sudo apt install qtcreator ; sudo apt install qt5-default; sudo apt install libqt5serialport5-dev; mkdir build; cd build; qmake ../BuildDltViewer.pro; make;  sudo make install; sudo ldconfig

  echo "dlt-viewer installation complete"
}


CheckIfDltExists
SetUpEnvForDlt
```